# Joomla and Wordpress RSS

Tags: android, wordpress, joomla, rss

Im' developing an Android rss app.
When I use joomla rss everything run correctly, instead with wordpress rss if I change category before 15,20 sec the first news list downloaded remain    for all others category, if I wait 20+ sec, everythings run correctly like joomla rss.

WordPress Rss:

http://www.cosenzachannel.it/feed/

Joomla Rss:

http://www.cosenzachannel.it/bkoldsite/index.php?format=feed&type=rss

Both rss are correct, because if I insert it inside web browser bar correct page is open.

Pls guys I need help, the app it's almost done..

Thanks Guys and have a good day.

Francesco.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange because its not the usual WordPress feed scheme

But if you use the RSS Autodiscovery link in the source code (or a plugin like "RSS Icon in URL Bar" for Firefox) you'll find a correct RSS feed for any category.

For example :

http://www.cosenzachannel.it/bkoldsite/brutium-cosenza.feed?type=rss

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answar, I hava no necessary reputation to vote you,otherwise  I would have done :). I'll try to use this pluging. I hope that it will works, I'm freaking out for this problem. Thank Again:)

Comment: A question, if rss is not correct, why if I copy it in a browser bar , and I run it,  I can see rss feed?